# Name of expression / function: ab / (a*a + b*b)

Tags: terminology

Does this expression:

$$f(a, b) = \frac{ab}{a^2 + b^2} \equiv \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}}$$

have a name?

**Comments**

I am unaware of a standard name for this expression, but I would refer to it as something like "pseudo-ratio" or "symmetric-ratio" because it shares some of the properties of a ratio, e.g.:

$$f(\lambda a, \lambda b) = f(a, b)$$

and equals to zero if one of the argument is 0 but the other one is not, but, unlike the ratio, it is symmetric, e.g.:

$$f(a, b) = f(b, a)$$

Obviously, there is plenty of functions with such properties.

Comment: This is not of research level, but let me answer. Your expression has no name, but you can give it a name (e.g. norok2's function).

Comment: Regarding the "ratio-like properties", the keyword you want is that $f$ is a "[homogeneous function of degree $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)".

Comment: It's the harmonic mean of $\frac ab$ and $\frac ba$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Could be named as half the harmonic mean of the ratio of a and b and the ratio of b and a, but also the half of the inverse of the arithmetic mean of the ratio of a and b and the ratio of b and a, but that is not a simple name, its a little more than a description of the operations involved.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Harmonic mean has $2$ in the numerator.